# dynamic SQL statement for deleting the data in all tables of a particular database in sql server based on filter (where) condition

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I would like to write a dynamic SQL which will delete the data in all the tables of particular database where [deleted]=1. I would also want to show the number of records which are getting deleted from each table. my database name is Test1. So, my normal query for one table is:

delete from Test1.DimCustomer where [deleted]=1 ( I want to make it dynamic for all table in Test1 database

As, i am going to do this in production for all the tables in a database, I would like to know the row counts of the records getting deleted. Also, I would like to know the backout plan for this dynamic query. So, can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system views to help you build dynamic sql. Something like this should work for you.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = 'begin transaction;'

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select count(*), TableName = ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + ' from ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + ' where [deleted] = 1; delete from ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + ' where [deleted] = 1;'
from sys.tables t
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id

select @SQL = @SQL + 'rollback transaction;'

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Once you are comfortable you can uncomment the last line to test it. Then change the rollback to a commit.